# Word automation server-side not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ms-word, office-interop

PREFACE: Yes, I know that Microsoft does not recommend this.  However, this server is internal-facing in a heavily restricted VLAN.

The goal is to automatically generate specific types of reports that I could not get formatted properly using the Office XML.  One of the reasons Microsoft does not recommend this is that the user account must be interactive (i.e. NOT ASPNET).  So if I set the application pool identity to run as a user, I no longer get COM errors, but Word still will not open using the following test code:

```
//Just checking if Word can be accessed
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
app.Visible = true;
```

I do not get any errors, but Word will not open.  This works when I use it on my development machine debugging with Visual Studio, but on my test machine when deployed I get nothing.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say Word will not open, do you mean that you don't see Word's user interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the application pool is running under user account, it does not mean that it is interactive and can access your desktop. You can check the list of running processes to find out if Word is there.

Comment: So WINWORD.EXE was listed.  For some reason, the application did not open (even using app.Visible = true), but the file was still created.

Answer (score 0):

*As you already know: Office Interop/Automation is NOT supported by MS in "server-like scenarios" (which IIS/ASP.NET is a special kind of)... see [KB257757](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757)*

Your options include several libtraries (free and commercial) - for example:

- [MS OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) (free)
- [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial)

Since Windows Vista several changes have been introduced to stop any Windows Service (IIS is just some special one) from doing anything "desktop-like" - this is due to security issues... to resolve such a situation you would need to circumvent those security measures implemented by MS - which I absolutely do NOT recommend...

Comment: A UI is not required to perform Word Automation, doom and gloom warnings notwithstanding.

Comment: @RobertHarvey depends on the exact features you use... but that is not the main point IMHO... please read the MS link at the top of my answer...

Comment: I understand that it is not supported or recommended.  However, it is still possible to run.  The OpenXML is not good for advanced formatting.  As I mentioned, I know MS does not support it, but as I said security is not an issue, which is the reason MS does not recommend)

Comment: @pendraggon87 security is not the only reason MS does not support it, there technical reasons and also legal ones!

Comment: Correct about the legal issues.  However, since this is internal for a small team, and we all have legitimate licenses there is no legal issue.  For technical issues, there are definitely performance issues, it might hang, etc.  It is an ugly stopgap, but management does not want to shell out for Apose or other commercial products, at least until they see the benefit.  It's a weird catch 22 - they won't pay until they see the results, but hard to show the results unless they pay.  Until then I am stuck with this solution :(

Comment: @pendraggon87 Aspose and others have test licenses which can help with such a catch22...